# Type hinting in PHP constructors?

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Is there anything to stop me from type hinting like this within the `__construct()` parentheses?

```
<?php

    class SomeClass extends BaseClass {

        public function __construct(array $someArray) {

            parent::__construct($someArray);
        }
```

Or can I only do it like this?

```
<?php

    class SomeClass extends BaseClass {

        public function __construct($someArray = array()) {

            parent::__construct($someArray);
        }
```

**Edit:**

This is what works: (Thanks @hakra and @Leigh)

```
<?php

    class SomeClass extends BaseClass {

        public function __construct( array $someArray = NULL ) {

            parent::__construct( (array) $someArray);
        }
```

To me it looks nice and clean and I know exactly what it supposed to mean.

Comment: Looks legit - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php why not try out?

Comment: You can do both: __construct(array $arr=array())

Comment: You've already typed out the code, why didn't you just try running it?

Comment: @Pekka, Yeah I guess I just have to test it :)

Comment: I need to be able to have the array optional. F.ex. __construct(array $someArr = false). Do you think it's valid?

Comment: Never mind, I'll just try it out ;)

Comment: Type hints and default values are not the same thing. Just because the default value is an empty array does not impose a requirement that a passed argument must be an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so:

```
public function __construct(array $someArray = NULL)
{
    $someArray = (array) $someArray;
    parent::__construct($someArray);
    ...
```

The case here is to make use of the `= NULL` exception of the rule. The next line:

```
    $someArray = (array) $someArray;
```

is just some shorthand to convert `NULL` into an empty array and otherwise leave the array an array as-is (a so called *[cast<sup>Docs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to array*):

> Converting `NULL` to an array results in an empty array.

(from: *[Converting to array<sup>Docs</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)*)

Sure you could write it even shorter:

```
public function __construct(array $someArray = NULL)
{
    parent::__construct((array) $someArray);
}
```

but it does not explain it that well.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise there was a `NULL` exception to the rule.

Comment: Thanks guys for these real good explanations. I'm trying to vote you guys up but I just get some boring messages.

Comment: Ok, I tried this method out and it worked perfectly. To me it looks great doing it like @hakra described in this posts short method. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is type hinting with no default, stating that a parameter **must** be given, and it's type **must** be an array

`public function __construct(array $someArray) {`

---

This is providing the default value for the argument if no parameter is passed, without a typehint.

`public function __construct($someArray = array()) {`

---

They are two different things.

In the second instance you can call the function with no parameters and it will work, but the first will not.

If you want, you can combine the two, to specify an default and specify the required type.

`public function __construct(array $someArray = array()) {`

Or as @hakre has stated, you can do:

`public function __construct(array $someArray = NULL) {`

Comment: No must if you make it optional `(array $someArray = NULL)`, check for NULL, make it optional.

Comment: `__construct(array $someArray)` will not accept `null` as its argument.

Comment: `array $someArray = array()` will work fine, using `null` is just misleading in my opinion.

Comment: @Jack You're right, it can only have NULL supplied as a default value.